# Post request keeps inserting null values into MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Using fetch API to send a post request from two forms when the button add household is clicked the /addcustomer route works but the /add household route just adds null values into the database except for the predefined values of `date_created` and `userid`. I checked on the client side and the data is being sent properly but it is using the text/html content type even though I specified to use multiform data. Here is the code:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

// Select the label element
const fileInputLabel = document.querySelector('.fileInputLabel');

// Listen for changes in the file input
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Get the selected file
    const file = fileInput.files[0];

    // Check if a file is selected
    if (file) {
        // Update the label text with the file name
        fileInputLabel.textContent = "Uploaded Picture!";
    } else {
        // If no file is selected, revert to the default label text
        fileInputLabel.textContent = 'Uploaded image!';
    }
});

document.getElementById('addHousehold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let rightForms = document.querySelectorAll('.right-form');
    


    // Iterate over each right-form
    rightForms.forEach((form, index) => {
        let formData = new FormData();

        // Get data from inputs in the current form
        let inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input, select');
        inputs.forEach(input => {
            if (input.type === 'file') {
                // If the input is a file input, append the file to the FormData object
                formData.append(input.name, input.files[0]);
            } else {
                formData.append(input.name, input.value);
            }
        });

        // Log the FormData object
        console.log(formData);

        // Send the form data to the Express.js API
        fetch('/addCustomer', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                
                //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(formData => {
            console.log('Data sent successfully:', formData);
            // Optionally, update the UI to reflect the successful submission
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending data:', error);
            // Optionally, update the UI to indicate the error
        });
    });
});
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const addHouseholdButton = document.getElementById('addHousehold');
    addHouseholdButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        
        const address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        const apt = document.getElementById('apt').value;
        const workphone = document.getElementById('workphone').value;
        const city = document.getElementById('city').value;
        const zipcode = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;

        const formData_contact = new FormData();
        formData_contact.append('address', address);
        formData_contact.append('apt', apt);
        formData_contact.append('workphone', workphone);
        formData_contact.append('city', city);
        formData_contact.append('zipcode', zipcode);
        
       

        fetch('/addhousehold', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData_contact,
            headers: {
                
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(formData_contact => {
            console.log('Data sent successfully:', formData_contact);
           
            // Optionally, update the UI to reflect the successful submission
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending data:', error);
            // Optionally, update the UI to indicate the error
        });
    });
});
```

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: '/public/images/' });





//Allows the user to use public folder to access views 
app.use(express.static('public'));

// MySQL connection configuration
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'letmein1',
  database: 'mydatabase'
});

//View engine 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Middle ware for sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mysecret', // Change this to a long random string
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Connect to the database
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
      console.error('Error connecting to MySQL database: ' + err.stack);
      return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database as ID ' + connection.threadId);
});

app.use(express.json());
// Middleware to parse the body of incoming requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Route to handle GET requests to the login page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', { user: req.session.user });
});

//Post request for login page
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE TRIM(username) = ? AND TRIM(password) = ?', [username.trim(), password.trim()], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
          res.send('Error retrieving user from database');
          return;
      }
      if (results.length > 0) {
        req.session.user =  results[0];
        res.redirect('/dashboard');

      } else {
        const message = 'Invalid Credentials';
        res.render('badLogin', { user: req.session.user });
      }
  });
});

//Dashboard 
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  // Check if the user is logged in
  if (req.session.user) {
    // If user is logged in, render the dashboard page
    res.render('dashBoard', { user: req.session.user });
  } else {
    // If user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.user = null;
  res.redirect('/');
}); 

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', { user: req.session.user });
});

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/addCustomer', upload.single('profilePicture'), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.user || !req.session.user.id) {
    res.status(403).send('User not authenticated');
    return;
  }
  const { name, dateOfBirth, relation, Year, Make, Model, VIN, CellPhone, address, apt, workphone, city, zipcode } = req.body;

  connection.query('INSERT INTO customers (name, profile_picture, dateOfBirth, relation, year, make, model, vin, cellphone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [name, req.file.filename, dateOfBirth, relation, Year, Make, Model, VIN, CellPhone], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error storing customer data:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Error storing customer data');
      return;
    }

    console.log(req.body );

 
    
    });
  });

  app.post('/addhousehold', (req, res) => {
    // Check if the user is authenticated or any other necessary checks
    if (!req.session.user) {
        // Handle unauthenticated user
        res.status(403).send('User not authenticated');
        return;
    }

    const { address, apt, workphone, city, zipcode } = req.body;

    connection.query('INSERT INTO household (address, apt, work_phone, city, zipcode, date_created, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)', [address, apt, workphone, city, zipcode, req.session.user.id], (householdError, householdResults, householdFields) => {
        if (householdError) {
            console.error('Error storing household data:', householdError);
            res.status(500).send('Error storing household data');
            return;
        }
        console.log(req.body);

        console.log('Household data stored successfully');
        res.status(200).send('Customer and household data stored successfully');
    });
});



/*app.post('/addCustomer', upload.single('profilePicture'), (req, res) => {
  const { name, dateOfBirth, relation, Year, Make, Model, VIN, CellPhone } = req.body;

  connection.query('INSERT INTO customers (name, profile_picture, dateOfBirth, relation, year, make, model, vin, cellphone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [name, req.file.filename, dateOfBirth, relation, Year, Make, Model, VIN, CellPhone], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error storing customer data:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Error storing customer data');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Customer data stored successfully');
    res.status(200).send('Customer data stored successfully');
 

    const { address, apt, workPhone, city, zipcode, userId } = req.body;
  connection.query('INSERT INTO household (address, apt, work_phone, city, zipcode, date_created, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)', [address, apt, workPhone, city, zipcode, userId], (householdError, householdResults, householdFields) => {
    if (householdError) {
      console.error('Error storing household data:', householdError);
      res.status(500).send('Error storing household data');
      return;
    }

    console.log('Household data stored successfully');
    res.status(200).send('Customer and household data stored successfully');
  });
});
}); */



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I checked to see if the values being entered match the constraints of the attributes in the database so that is not the case.

I also `console.log()`-ed the values gather in the fetch API that routes to /addhousehold and it prints the values correctly.

When I try to `console.log` the `req.body` on the server's side the only contents I can see is name, date of birth , relation, year, make, model , vin and cellphone. The values relating to household is undefined and not listed so that tells me there is a problem with the way the server is receiving the data. I am thinking that the header is not sending the data in the correct format but every time I try to change the header type it still sends the post request as html/text.

Comment: In your `fetch '/addhousehold'` , what happens if you replace the empty headers with `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}`
?

Comment: Actually, try `multipart/form-data`, as the body is FormData, and according to MDN It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: if you do `console.log(req.body)` do you see the correct values?

Comment: One thing that's different - in your first `click` event handler, you're filling up the `formData` within a loop. And in your second `click` event handler, you're picking up specific values individually, and adding them to  `formData_contact`. Can you verify that the values you're using for `formData_contact` are non-null values? What happens if you temporarily disable the `click` event handler in your first code snippet (the one handling the data from `.right-form`). Does your request for `/addHousehold` go through correctly?

Comment: When I switch the content type to application nothing happens it still sends the request as text/html

Comment: When I do console.log(req.body) I see the attributes in the customers table not the household table

Comment: Im going to disable the event click and see what happens ill keep you posted !